# Drawing LineChart Javafx with Floats

Tags: javafx-2, fxml, linechart

is it possible to use float #'s on an axis in a Javafx chart? LineChart specifically?

```
NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis(); NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();
LineChart<Number,Number> dataChart = new LineChart<Number,Numer>(); 
Float d = 1e-9f,t =1e-8f,z =1e-7f;
XYChart.Series series = new XYChart.Series<>();
series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(200,d));
series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(300,z));
series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(100,t));

dataChart.getData().clear();
dataChart.getData().add(series);
```

What I mean is my pressure values come in on the range of of 1e-9 - 1e-7, and I want the axis to show these values in scientific notation like 1e-9 or 5e-7 etc... How would I go about doing this?

Im using JavaFx FXML, so the code is a little scattered, so I am not including all of it here.

[image]